# es6 import and reference d.ts in same file

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Im trying vscode to give a suggestion obtained from a type declared in file d.ts instead of deducing the type from es6 import.

index.js

```
// I include the type of MyClass in separate declaration file
///<reference path="types.d.ts">

//I import MyClass, but i want its type to be suggested from declaration file
import MyClass from "MyClass.js"

...

let instance = new MyClass(...)
```

vscode only suggest the type from d.ts file if i remove the import statement.
Is it possible to force vscode to suggest the type in d.ts instead of es6 import class?

When i say vscode suggestion, i refer when you put the cursor over the MyClass() and vscode shows a tooltip with the class description

Comment: Afaict, the `/// <reference …>` should be placed in the *MyClass.js* module itself, not in all the modules importing it. Or just use *MyClass.d.ts* instead of *types.d.ts*.

Comment: I moved ```/// <reference ...> ``` to MyClass.js and i have the same problem. It shows correctly only if i remove the import statement, and i dont want that beacuse i want to build the lib as a esmodule and not providing the MyClass symbol in window object